# Hide UISlider thumb image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uislider

I am trying to create a UISlider without the thumb image.

How can I do this, this is my code so far:

```
UISlider *sli = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:progressView.frame];
    [sli setThumbImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sli setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [sli setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ProgressBlueCap.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sli setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ProgressBlueCapRight.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a transparent 1x1 image? I don't that it's possible to remove the thumb that easily.

Comment: There is a user-interaction problem with using a UISlider for this. When a user sees a thumb, they know they should tap on the thumb to drag it. If you don't have a thumb, then they might think they can tap anywhere on the slider - and expect it to move to that value. This isn't going to happen. This means that you have an invisible thumb, but the user has to touch and drag the invisible element to use the slider...

Answer (score 63, accepted):

### Much simpler:

Objc

```
[sli setThumbImage:[[[UIImage alloc] init] autorelease] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Swift version

```
sli.setThumbImage(UIImage(), for: .normal)
```

Comment: This is not draggable!

Comment: If you want to make this work _and_ be draggable, then you'd have to subclass and override the hitTest.

Answer (score 17):

The ***easiest*** way is simply setting the Thumb Tint colour to **Clear** on the Interface Builder - like so...

[image]

Voila!

Comment: the downside of this solution is that the slider still thinks it has a thumb which is ~40px wide, so when you drag all the way to the left/right, there is still some of the track coloured/uncoloured as it is being drawn 'behind' the thumb.

Comment: This only works for me on iOS 8.3 and above.  For some reason, for iOS 8.0 - 8.2, the slider still shows despite setting the tint color to clear.

Comment: not working, with clear color you will have a small line

Comment: How can we programtically set the thumb tint color?

Answer (score 12):

This is an old thread but I found it so someone else may as well.

Here's a solution to this in Swift. I'm creating a blank UIImage here programatically and then assigning it to the thumb.

```
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1), false, 0)
    UIColor.clear.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    if let blankImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
        slider.setThumbImage(blankImg, for: .normal)
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: This worked for me!  In Objective C my code looked like this:
    `CGRect thumbRect = CGRectMake(0,0,1,1);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(1,1), false, 0);
    [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill(thumbRect);
    UIImage* blankImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext( );
[slider setThumbImage:blankImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: Thanks for this - very charming

Answer (score 1):

One line solution:

```
[_slider setThumbImage:[UIImage new] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try subclassing `UISlider` and override `-thumbRectForBounds:trackRect:value:` to return NSZeroRect.  If that doesn't do it, try overriding  `-thumbImageForState:` to return nil.